# Showing the classes in the table, but the textboxes just stay stagnant

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, I want that when a value is chosen from the `afterprint` select box, the relevant element is shown. By default it is hidden.

The problem is that when I do for the stapling class, it works fine. But, when I come to punching and the other groups, the heading goes to the left but its relevant textbox just stays at its place and does not come to the left like the heading. I have tried a lot but cannot seem to get it right. I will appreciate if you guys can help me out with this. I am using Bootstrap CSS for style sheet.

The HTML and Javascript(Jquery) codes are below:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="imgtable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><center>Service Name</center></th>
                <th>Paper Media</th>
                <th>Paper Size</th>
                <th>After Printing</th>
                <th><input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" class="btn btn-info" onclick="showrow(this)" style="width:50px;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="afterprint" id="afterprint" class="form-control" onchange="unselect();">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value='staple'>Stapling</option>
                        <option value='punch'>Punching</option>
                        <option value='fold'>Folding</option>
                        <option value='crease'>Creasing</option>
                        <option value='perforation'>Perforation</option>
                        <option value='number'>Numbering</option>
                        <option value='book'>Booklet Binding</option>
                        <option value='spiral'>Spiral Binding</option>
                        <option value='tape'>Tape Binding</option>
                        <option value='wino'>Wino Binding</option>
                        <option value='folder'>Folder Binding</option>
                        <option value='tablecal'>Table Calendar Binding</option>
                        <option value='spicalendar'>Calendar Spiral</option>
                        <option value='trim'>Trimming</option>
                        <option value='cut'>Cutting</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="test1">
                <td class='stapling'>Stapling</td>
                <td class='punching'>Punching</td>
                <td class='folding'>Folding</td>
                <td class='creasing'>Creasing</td>
                <td class='perforation'>Perforation</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="test1">
                <td>
                    <select name="stapling" id="stapling" class="form-control stapling" >
                        <option></option>
                            <?php  
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM tstapling";
                                $service = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)) { 
                                    echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";    
                                } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="punching" id="punching" class="form-control punching" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="folding" id="folding" class="form-control folding" onchange="getProdDet(this)">
                        <option></option>
                        <?php  
                           $query = "SELECT * FROM tfolding";
                           $service = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                           while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)) { 
                                echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";    
                            } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="creasing" id="creasing" class="form-control creasing" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php  
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tperforation";
                    $service = mysql_query($query);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($service)) { 
                            echo "<input type='text' name='perforation' id='perforation' class='form-control perforation' value='$row[price]' >";

                        } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('.test1').hide();
   $('.stapling').hide();
   $('.punching').hide();
   $('.folding').hide();
   $('.creasing').hide();
   $('.perforation').hide();
});

function unselect() {
    var x = $('#afterprint').val();
    alert(x);

    if(x == "staple" | x == "punch" | x == "fold" | x == "crease" | x == "perforation") {
        $('.test1').show();
        if(x == "staple") {
            $('.stapling').show();
        } else if(x == "punch") {
            $('.punching').show();
        } else if(x == "fold") {
            $('.folding').show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Bitwise OR [`|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)? You should use `||` and Also move your function `unselect` outside document ready handler

Comment: @Satpal, before I had used the || and a funny thing the function was not working. When I used |, it is. Kindly please let me know what is the problem

Comment: @Satpal, i have also kept the unselect() function outside the document ready handler. I guess I made a mistake of putting it in the document ready function when I posted the question. Thank you for that.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this problem? I will appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.